# Alphabetical Pyramid

Tags: c, triangle

I'm trying to make a program that takes input number of rows from the user and prints this type of pattern for example if "number of rows: 5", then it should print this pattern
[OUTPUT I WANT](https://i.stack.imgur.com/k3ymH.png)

I wrote this C code,

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
    int rows, i, j, k;

    // Take input for the number of rows
    printf("Enter the number of rows: ");
    scanf("%d", &rows);

    for (i = 1; i <= rows; i++) {
        k = 'A';
        for (j = 1; j <= 2 * rows - 1; j++) {
            // Adjusted condition to reduce one space in all rows
            if ((j <= rows - i || j >= rows + i) && !(i == 1 && j == rows)) {
                printf("%c", k);
                j < rows ? k++ : k--;
            } else {
                if (j != rows) {
                    printf(" ");
                }
                if (j == rows) {
                    k--;
                }
            }
        }
        printf("\n");
    }

    return 0;
}
```

And after execution of this above code I'm getting this type of answer
[UNDESIRED RESULT](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UQgWq.png)

Comment: Your output (desired and undesired) should be included in the question as formatted text rather than an image or a link to an image.

Comment: looks like you're close... some general advice, get out of the habit of looping from 1 to `<= n`. Indices in C start at 0, and you loop from 0 to `< n`. You're not indexing arrays here, but you will be soon if you haven't already.

Answer (score 2):

Reduce complexity. Break down what your program actually has to do into smaller steps.

For an input of N, your function has to print N lines.

```c
int main(void) {
    int n = 5;
    
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {

    }
}
```

On the first line you need to print N letters in the sequence from `A` to `Z` and zero spaces. On the second line you need to print N - 1 letters and one space. And so on.

```c
int main(void) {
    int n = 5;
    
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < n - i; j++) {
            printf("%c", 'A'+j);
        }

        for (int j = 0; j < i; j++) {
            printf(" ");
        }

        printf("\n");
    }
}
```

Output so far:

```
ABCDE
ABCD
ABC
AB
A
```

Now, you just need to reverse these steps to print the end of each line.

```c
int main(void) {
    int n = 5;

    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < n - i; j++) {
            printf("%c", 'A'+j);
        }

        for (int j = 0; j < i; j++) {
            printf(" ");
        }

        for (int j = 0; j < i - 1; j++) {
            printf(" ");
        }

        for (int j = n - i - 1; j >= 0; j--) {
            // Skip the first letter
            if (j == n - 1) continue;

            printf("%c", 'A'+j);
        }

        printf("\n");
    }
}
```

Output:

```
ABCDEDCBA
ABCD DCBA
ABC   CBA
AB     BA
A       A
```

With some math those two loops to print the spaces can now be reduced to one.

```c
int main(void) {
    int n = 5;

    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < n - i; j++) {
            printf("%c", 'A'+j);
        }

        for (int j = 0; j < (i - 1) * 2 + 1; j++) {
            printf(" ");
        }

        for (int j = n - i - 1; j >= 0; j--) {
            if (j == n - 1) continue;

            printf("%c", 'A'+j);
        }

        printf("\n");
    }
}
```

Which could further be reduced to:

```c
        int spaces = i == 0 ? 0 : (i - 1) * 2 + 1;
        printf("%*.*s", spaces, spaces, " ");
```

Alternatively, if we create strings representing the forward and backwards parts of the string, we can use `printf` to control printing much as we did with the spaces in the previous snippet.

```c
int main(void) {
    int n = 5;

    char str[n+1];
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) str[i] = 'A' + i;
    str[n] = '\0';
    // For n=5, this is "ABCDE"

    char rev[n];
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) rev[i] = str[n - i - 2];
    rev[n-1] = '\0';
    // For n=5 this is "DCBA"

    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        printf(
          "%-*.*s%*.*s\n",
          n, n - i, str,
          // Conditionally specify length for first loop.
          n - 1, (i == 0 ? n - 1 : n - i), rev
        );
    }
}
```

Note: as both `str` and `rev` are always being printed with a width specifier, you *could* eliminate the null terminators on both arrays.

Comment: My apologies to @Chris for accidentally adding a paragraph (and then removing it) here. Mistakes happen... Again, my apologies.

Comment: Mistakes happen. You took care of it before I even knew something had gone wrong, so kudos.

Answer (score 1):

You could consider leaving it all to printf, and do it in one printf line:

```
int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    for (auto str : { "", "M", "ABCDEEDCBA", "ABCDEDCBA" })
        for (int L = strlen(str), i = 0; i < L / 2; i++)
            printf(
                "%-*.*s"
                "%*c\b" // backspace to erase one space because printf doesn't honour a 0 count of chars.
                "%*.*s\n",
                L / 2 - i, L / 2 - i, str,
                2 * i + L % 2 + 1, ' ', // one more space than we need is to be erased by backspace
                L / 2 - i, L / 2 - i, str + L / 2 + i + L % 2);
    return 0;
}
```

Yes, it does requires the more advanced feature of printf.

Regards.

Comment: The question specifies C, but the range-based for loop is clearly a C++ feature.